# Config file for enable-linger / disable-linger?

Tags: systemd, login, logind

I know that `loginctl enable-linger <user>` and `loginctl disable-linger <user>` can be used to enable/disable linger for a user, and the status shown with `loginctl show-user <user>` (`Linger=<yes/no>`).

I also know that these (at least at the time of writing) work by manipulating `/var/lib/systemd/linger/<user>`, and that `loginctl` has some configuration in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` (or `[...].d/*.conf`).

However, all the configuration options mentioned in `man 5 logind.conf` seem to be 'global' options, not including `Linger`; is there no file-based (in `/etc` or similar rather than `/var`) way to set the linger option for a user?

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent of `loginctl enable-linger <user>` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` would be `KillExcludeUsers`

from logind.conf(5):

> These settings take space-separated lists of usernames that override the *KillUserProcesses=* setting. A user name may be added to *KillExcludeUsers=* to exclude the processes in the session scopes of that user from being killed even if *KillUserProcesses=yes* is set.

Answer (score 5):

`loginctl enable-linger <user>` does permanently enable it even across reboots. You can verify with `ls /var/lib/systemd/linger/` which lists all users where linger is enabled (filename == username). One of the tasks for `loginctl` is to create/remove the file.